# Handle "Out-of-Gamut" Color in RGB to CIEL*a*b* to RGB Conversions

Tags: c++, image, colors

I've got functions (c++) that convert a game image (SDL2 SDL_Surface) from RGB through CIEXYZ to CIEL*a*b* so that adjustments to hue, brightness, saturation, will be more visually natural than in HSV space. That works, with the exception of those pixels that are adjusted out of the RGB gamut in the process.

While it is easy enough to force a value back into gamut by:

- individually cropping subpixel values below 0 to 0 and above 255 to 255, or
- compressing and moving the whole pixel or whole image into the 0-255 range by dividing by (max-min) and subtracting min/(max-min);

these options lead to gross artifacts when doing multiple operating on the same image. I am looking for the least destructive method of handling out-of-gamut subpixels in code. Digging through many pages of Google results least to hundreds of Photoshop links, a few design oriented links and references to CMSs like LittleCMS.

I need an algorithmic solution to put into c++ code.

*Note:* Just doing some basic experimentation, using linear compression on the entire image leads to massive loss of brightness over hundreds of iterations with calculations happening as floats. Further insight into the sigmoid compression comment below is most welcome.

Comment: what about storing data in a space large enough to represent it?  There are hue, saturation abd brightness changes to RGB 888 pixels that cannot fundamantally be represented in that space.

Comment: That is the problem exactly. I **need** to go back to RGBA8888 since these "images" are actually "sprites", or whatever you want to call them, that get passed to SDL2 for conversion to SDL_Texture and then SDL_Render'ed to the screen. I'm trying to adapt the photorealism of Lab manipulation for use in a game.

Comment: Keep both the display sprite *and* the real image data which has a better gamut.  Or keep the original sprite, transformations done to it, and the current result.  When a new transformation applies, compose it with existing transformations, and redo it from the original.

Comment: Maybe consider using a sigmoid-like compression function to map your out-of-gamut values onto 0 - 255?  ie. make it mostly linear over, say 20 - 235, and map the rest of the gamut into the last 20 positions at top and bottom?

Comment: @Yakk, The idea of keeping a float copy certainly works, but since the goal is to have this work on most SDL2 platforms -- including ARM devices like tablets and phones -- I'd like to avoid the unnecessary RAM consumption by finding a good gamut management algorithm.

Comment: @JoeZ, I like the idea, but I have no idea in advance how far out of gamut any particular pixel might end up being. So, I have no clue how to figure out how much to compress. I also cannot determine whether to compress the whole image or just the out of gamut pixels or apply the compression in a Gaussian-like distribution around the out-of-gamut pixels.

Comment: The gamut of the other color space is only a finite amount larger than RGB.  So you can bound it.  The real problem is that this involves creating yet another color space: you have to distinguish between RGB and RGB-super-gamut.  Plus, if the difference between gamuts is large, you will get resolution artifacts.

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is bouncing between gamuts, so you get a recursive loss:  "massive loss of brightness over hundreds of iterations."  You really ought to keep your entire image in one color space, and only do one color-space conversion at the end if you can help it.  Any compression you apply will end up being applied repeatedly.

Comment: @Yakk You both have hit the nail on the head -- it is impossible to keep fidelity over many generations of space-to-space conversions. Now someone write an answer so that I can accept it! :)

Comment: @JoeZ You both have hit the nail on the head -- it is impossible to keep fidelity over many generations of space-to-space conversions. Now someone write an answer so that I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental issue you face is multiple conversions between color spaces.  If the conversion isn't lossless, then you will get cumulative artifacts.

The better solution is to maintain all of your imagery in one color space and do all of your manipulation within that color space.  Treat conversion as a one-way street, converting a *copy* to RGB for display.  Do not convert back and forth.